# How can I call an async method in StatelessWidget.build method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have below code in flutter. In `initialRoute:` attribute, it needs to call `isLoggedIn()` method which is an async function. I got an error saying I need to call `await` in a `async` function. But the `build` method is overridden from its parent class which is not `async` method. How can I call an `await` inside an overridden method?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: await isLoggedIn() ? '/': '/login',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/': (BuildContext context) {
          return MyHomePage(title: 'Home Page');
        },
        '/login': (BuildContext context) {
          return Login();
        },
      }

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me it is impossible to do what you are trying to do.

As you mention isLoggedIn is async which is gonna take time to calculate, meanwhile build method complete build. You can use **futureBuilder** to do async task in Stateless widget but as this is your initial route, you have to provide it, so again it will not work.

I recommend you to add splash screen, where you can calculate mean call that method and find out navigation.

Answer (score 5):

When I had this problem, I solved it by putting the await not inside MyApp.build,  but in the MyApp call in main. Like this:

```
Future <Widget> selectStartPage () async {
    return await isLoggedIn() ? HomePage (): Login (),
}

Future<void> main() async {
   // whatever setup you need...
   runApp (MyApp (await selectStartPage()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   final Widget startPage;
   MyApp (this.startPage);

   @override Widget build (BuildContext context){
      return MaterialApp(
         title: '',
         theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
         ),
         initialRoute: startPage,
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: A good way, upvote, don't forget to add this line to async main: `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest it would be a better option to create an authentication router widget to handle the logged in status of the app that way if the user logs out of the app the navigation can change automatically. i.e:

```
initialRoute: '/user-auth'
```

Then is a UserAuth widget you can run your logged in logic.